# How should aggregation and association be thought of

Tags: uml, associations, aggregation, composition, class-diagram

Let's say we have a supermarket chain and a number of supermarkets belong to it.

If the chain ceases to exist the supermarkets will have to shut down. This could be implemented in UML using a composition relationship. On what side of the association should the filled-in diamond be located?

- Should it be like `Chain----<.>supermarket`  ? Or `chain<.>-----supermarket`) ?
- Should I think of it as the supermarkets belong to the chain or the chain has supermarkets?

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/403037/uml-aggregation-how-can-the-whole-exist-without-its-parts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In UML, you put the composition diamond next to the class that *composes* another. In your example, An individual of type `Chain` *composes* [1] several individuals of type `Supermarket`, so the black diamond goes on the `Chain` end of the association.

---

[1] Some people pronounce this "`Chain` *has* `Supermarkets`", which is indistinguishable from a different sense of the word "has", as in "`Chain` *has* `name`".

Comment: +1 for the accurate answer.  Since you're at OMG, I'd like to bring to your attention the terrible ambiguity of the verb "to compose":  compose means ["to be part of something"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/fr/dictionnaire/anglais/composing) according to the Oxford dictionary.  This is exactly the contrary of the way you use this verb that you use in the sense "to apply composition".  This kind of ambiguity  certainly contributes to entertain the doubts about the right side.   Would you mind finding a less ambiguous phrasing ?

Comment: Thanks for the +1. As a native English speaker, I have never run across "to compose" used to mean "to be _part_ of something". That word sense is unsupported by any other dictionary I can find. A composite composes parts. If you still feel strongly about it, you can submit an issue, or a change request, by sending email to issues@omg.org.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback ! I’m not a native speaker and therefore have to rely on dictionaries ;-) I thought Oxford was a reliable and comprehensive one.

Comment: You are welcome. You may want to reconsider your use of the OED for understanding modern English. 